# Regex.Replace finding variable width and height in an html string and replacing with a set value

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that will look for the width and height attributes in a string (which will always be an html iframe) and replace the values that it has.

What I have is a string where ### could be any value, and not necessarily always 3 digits.

```
string iFrame = <iframe width="###" height="###" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to end up with set values for the width and height:

```
<iframe width="315" height="215" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxxxx" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I tried this, but am not good with regular expressions:

```
iFrame = Regex.Replace(iFrame, "width=\".*\"", "width=\"315\"");
iFrame = Regex.Replace(iFrame, "height=\".*\"", "height=\"215\"");
```

which resulted in:

```
<iframe width="315" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

which is not what I want.  Can someone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Replace your patterns to this:

> "width=\"([0-9]{1,4})\""

and

> "height=\"([0-9]{1,4})\""

Basically, you were using `.` which performs a greedy-capture. Meaning it grabs as many characters as possible. The patterns above look for any number character `[0-9]` that repeats between 1 and 4 times `{1,4}`. Which is what you are really looking for.

Comment: thank you for the response that worked for me! and the explanation.  regular expressions are on my list of things to learn...

Comment: Glad it helped. Also, do a quick google search for RegEx pattern testers. They are often little programs that allow you to test your regex instantly. Probably the best way to learn.

Answer (score 3):

You are better off using the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse and query HTML. It handles HTML fragments well.

RegEx is not a good solution for parsing HTML, as [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) may convince you.

Comment: Is there any answer other than `RegEx is not a good solution for parsing HTML use HTML Agility Pack`. Even referred library is the same  always. I should save this string as a reputation hunter :)

Comment: @L.B - RegEx is _not_ a good solution for arbitrary HTML. And the library is a very good library, which is why it is referred to so often. Is this a problem?

Comment: Isn't there any other library, or is it always valid even for a simply parsing.

Comment: @L.B - It is good for HTML fragments, badly formed HTML and is fast. If you know the incoming format (and that it will not change or vary much), by all means, use RegEx.

Answer (score 3):

I agree that this isn't the best way to work with html. The problem with your example is the . in you regex which is matching all chars and spaces up to the last " in the string. Change it to the code below which only matches non-whitespace characters.

```
iFrame = Regex.Replace(iFrame, @"width=""[^\s]*""", "width=\"315\"");
iFrame = Regex.Replace(iFrame, @"height=""[^\s]*""", "height=\"215\"");
```